# Windows 7 routing with single NIC

Tags: windows, networking, routing, network-adapter

I have a PC with single NIC running windows 7.
This PC is a member of 180.x.x.0/24 network and is internet accessible.

Now, my brother brought another PC with single NIC.
I want to make it also internet accessible.
I have a dummy hub but the ISP assigned me only one IP.

So I assigned another IP 192.168.0.1 to my NIC with net mask 255.255.255.0.
And I assigned IP 192.168.0.100 to my brother's NIC with net mask 255.255.255.0 and default gateway 192.168.0.1.

I already have searched some article from this site and turned on the "IP routing enabled" feature in my PC by editing the registry.
But my brother cannot access the internet.
(Of course, I manually input the DNS info into 2ndary PC.)
It seems that my PC does not perform routing.
The ping test from my brother's to mine results fine using 192.168.0.1, and mine is still internet accessible.

Is there any way or solution for this?

I know about the ICS feature of windows, but it requires 2 NICs.

Another answered question says it's impossible.
Any idea?

https://serverfault.com/questions/180970/windows-server-2008r2-routing-with-single-nic

Comment: You need the Routing and Remote Access service. It isn't available with all editions of Windows 7. Which edition are we talking about? Home, Home Premium, Professional, Enterprise, or Ultimate?

Comment: @James, Thank you for your comment. I am using window 7 professional edition.

Answer (score 0):

Goto http://technet.microsoft.com and search for "windows 7 Internet Connection Sharing"
I found:
[how-to-share-internet-connection-using-ethernet-switch](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/b47b49c9-1882-412e-be4d-a08d5208d90d/how-to-share-internet-connection-using-ethernet-switch)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, as I mentioned in the body text, I have already considered the ICS but it requires two NICs while I have only one.

Comment: Read the "how to ... using-ethernet-switch". He has also only one NIC in his setup!

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do just won't work.  A public IP (180.x.x.0) can only talk to your private IP's (192.168.0.1) through a router with NAT.  It's by design.  ICS would solve that as it sets up a NAT router.  If you can't have two NIC's to run ICS, then you just need a router to translate the 180.x.x.0 to you and your brother's 192.168.0.x's.

Your hub does not NAT pubic IP's to private IP's  You need a router or ICS.